# JS Function within a function within that function and so on

Tags: javascript, function, nested, depth

Ok, I have being trying to find a solution for this for the past 3 hours...

I want to be able to create my own library, accessible function within function with function etc.

Here's what I want to do...

```
var outer=function()
{
    this.inner=function()
    {
        this.innermost=function()
        {
        alert("innermost");
        }
    }   
}
var outer=new outer;

function start()
{   
//I want to call it like this but fails!
outer.inner.innermost();    
}
```

Now this fails when I try to call the innermost. But if I just have a a function within a function, it works. For example:

```
var outer=function()
{
    this.inner=function()
    {
    alert("inner");
    }   
}
var outer=new outer; 

function start()
{   
// this works
outer.inner();  
}
```

All the examples I've found only show a function within a function.

I want to be able to create my own library of functions. With an easy way to access them, e.g.:

```
MyLib.SubLib.SubLib2.function
MyLib.SubLib.SubLib2.property
```

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.  Would I have to learn and use prototypes?

Comment: You may want to look into objects or into self-invoking functions that return objects.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is how you do it:

```
var outer = function() {
    this.inner = {
        innermost: function() {
            alert("innermost");
        }
    }
}
var outer = new outer;
outer.inner.innermost();
```

The reason why it didn't work the way you did it is because you define a function `inner` - so `outer.inner` is a function. You could do `var inner = new (outer.inner)();` and then call `inner.innermost();` but that's obviously ugly and not what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked,  is there a limitation on how deep the functions can go ?, would I be able to do outer.inner.innermost.inneragain(); ?